# VBA Copy And Paste Error

Tags: vba, excel

This is a bit of a trivial error but I cannot figure it out. I have a vba script that is copying and pasting a couple of items. It works on all but the last. The error is

> The information cannot be pasted because the Copy area and the paste
>   area are not the same size and shape. Try one of the following:
>
> 1. Click a single cell, and then paste. •
> 2. Select a rectangle that's the same size and shape, and then paste.

Here is the code:

```
Sub MakePropertyPage(propertyNum, aFile)
Dim sheetName As String
sheetName = "Prop " & propertyNum

'OPENS INDIVIDUAL WORKBOOKS TO PULL IN INPUT INFORMATION
Workbooks.Open Filename:=vpath & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & aFile & ".xlsb",                 UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True

Dim sourceRangeAsString As String, dest As Range, clearArea As Range
Dim sheetToEdit As Worksheet
Set sheetToEdit = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)

Set clearArea = sheetToEdit.Range("AL100:CC900")
clearArea.Delete

sourceRangeAsString = "RentRoll"
Set dest = sheetToEdit.Range("AL100")
Call CopyAndPaste(Workbooks(aFile & ".xlsb"), sourceRangeAsString, dest)

sourceRangeAsString = "Underwriting"
Set dest = sheetToEdit.Range("AL300")
Call CopyAndPaste(Workbooks(aFile & ".xlsb"), sourceRangeAsString, dest)

sourceRangeAsString = "Projections"
Set dest = sheetToEdit.Range("AL400")
Call CopyAndPaste(Workbooks(aFile & ".xlsb"), sourceRangeAsString, dest)

sourceRangeAsString = "RolloverCalculations"
dest = sheetToEdit.Range("AL500")
Call CopyAndPaste(Workbooks(aFile & ".xlsb"), sourceRangeAsString, dest)



'Close the workbook now that we are done with it
Workbooks(aFile & ".xlsb").Close savechanges:=False
End Sub

Sub CopyAndPaste(sourceFile, sourceRangeAsString, dest)
    Set source = sourceFile.Names(sourceRangeAsString).RefersToRange
    source.Copy
    dest.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    source.Copy
    dest.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `Set` here:

```
dest = sheetToEdit.Range("AL500")
```